# iOS8 iphone upside down rotation doesn't work fine

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8

Should it be a bug or I forgot something?

I added the following code in appDelegate

```
(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and the following in my viewController

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and this the project settings

[image]

the viewController rotate fine,but if I try to show a alert the result is the following

[image]

the some code for ios 7 works fine

Comment: What options do you have in the project settings?

Comment: I forgot to post the settings, I have now added in the question

Comment: Any News here ? It seems that the problem only appears with the UIAlertView, even in the final iOS8 version...

Comment: I think this is a bug. I have the same problem, it only affects iOS8. I reported it on Apple's Bug Tracker: 18780989